# How to add a countdown clock on html5?

Tags: html, clock

I was wondering how can you add a countdown clock? Im really having trouble trying to add a simple countdown clock with weeks, days, hours and seconds, lets say, ending at April 2? I just need help on how to make one on an html5 coding?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this with pure HTML5. Have you looked into jQuery or even just plain JavaScript for that matter? There are also js libraries you can download and use to get you up and running pretty quick with little to no coding. Google is your friend here man.